# The Suffering connection problem

Tags: pc, the-suffering

I recently downloaded The Suffering to my new laptop (Windows 8, my previous was Windows Vista), but whenever I try to play, it says I need to be connected to the internet, which is weird because my laptop is always connected (wifi). I've tried changing the settings on the compatibility-thing, but that doesn't work, and I've tried downloading it from a different site. Nothing works, so what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to run a game that's been converted into [an ad supported title](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Suffering_(video_game)#Freeware_release). This is why the internet connection is required. However, there are two ends to this connection, your laptop's connection and the server that's supposed to be serving the ads and authenticating your game. Those servers are no longer up.

You'll need to purchase a copy of the game that's not ad supported, thus, not requiring an internet connection.